# Getting the Full Path Of A File Upload Field In A Form in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, file, upload

I am using a file upload in PHP.  I want to get the Full PATH of the File Selected.  Is there any way i can get the full path in PHP??

For Eg: i uploaded a image from : "c:\upload\check.jpeg"
I want the full path.. as "c:\upload\check.jpeg".

i tried pathinfo, $_FILES. But no help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The path to the file on the client machine - no, but that is normally irrelevant...

Comment: yes the path of the client's machine.  Is it possible?

Comment: @Aby: you might be able to access it from javascript (not sure if its allowed or not) and then add it to the values being submitted by the form - but that would be the only way. Why would you need the local path?

Comment: @Neil E. Pearson: Hey thanks for replying.  so this wont work for the website on the localhost also.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Yes i need the complete path of the file which is uploaded. or just the information about the directory which can be seen in the file upload box.

Comment: correct. web apps are deliberately sandboxed to prevent servers from getting that sort of information. you may be able to do something with flash or java, but...yeah. icky. it sounds like you need a native desktop app. why not have a taste of cocoa or .net :)

Comment: @Neil E. Pearson:  I would love to implement this file upload on flash or java or cocoa or .net.  But i want to try it in PHP or Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably can't. Many browsers these days don't send that information, as it can give attackers information about the user's system.

Answer (score 1):

On the client side `fileinput.value` will give just the filename in Firefox and the full path in IE8. No browser will send the full path to the server as that would be a security issue.

However with IE (I've done this with IE8*) you can probably cheat a bit with JavaScript and put the path into a different text field to be sent with the form. Of course that would only work for IE. I would argue IE is broken since it allows you to do such nasty things.

*I wasn't sending the path to the server. I was creating a "stylish" file upload control for which I cheated by putting the selected filename in a separate text field and hid the actual file input. IE and FF differed in how the filename was displayed